# Uploading file in Selenium with python using sendKeys() is not working

Tags: python, html, selenium, sendkeys

When I try to upload a file using sendkeys, it doesn't give me an error, but the page shows a warning that an error has occurred when uploading the ad.
The html is in photo

[image]

python:

```
img='/home/user/directory/photo.jpg'
elm = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type='file']")
elm.send_keys(img)
```

the page https://www.milanuncios.com/publicar-anuncios-gratis/

What could be due to, in the event that there is no alternative in a python script.

Thanks for all.

Comment: I can't see anything bad on your code. Are you sure that the path is the right one? (I suppose you use Linux, if not your path is wrong!) Are you sure the driver is active?

Comment: @Phineas Xpath is working fine.Able to upload file with this. Probably it would be a file path issue

Comment: I mean the file path. You use Linux, right?

Comment: Yes I use linux, the code is supposed to be correct but when loading it the page gives the warning that an error has occurred while uploading the ad

Comment: I tried your code (albeit in windows) and it works fine with a test image. When you say "page shows a warning that an error has occurred when uploading the ad"  - what's the error? Does the devtools console say anything useful?

Comment: I don't think so there is something wrong with your code. Have you tried manually, are you able to upload the advt because I have tried from my end it is showing the same error. There might be something wrong with the website. Please check from your end.

Comment: It may be that it detects something because if you upload the photo manual it will allow the ad to be registered.Is there any other way in python to upload a photo.